# Facebook Android SDK logout listener

Tags: android, facebook, logout

i'm using facbook sdk in my application. when i logged in my application via facebook sdk, everything work perfectly, but when i open Facebook App and logout from Facebook App, my app still logged on. so how do i add a listener to listen logout event from Facebook SDK?

Comment: You cannot. It's not supported.

Answer (score 5):

This is an old questions, but I wanted to update with an answer.

In Facebook API 4.0 (As that is current as of writing) You can use an [AccessTokenTracker](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/AccessTokenTracker/).

```
    AccessTokenTracker accessTokenTracker = new AccessTokenTracker() {
        @Override
        protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(AccessToken accessToken, AccessToken accessToken2) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onCurrentAccessTokenChanged()");
            if (accessToken == null) {
                // Log in Logic
            } else if (accessToken2 == null) {
                // Log out logic
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: Upvoted but the "Log in logic" did not work - log out is fine. Also note the documentation says that if you are going to use the tracker you need to make sure it uses "startTracking" and "stopTracking" because internally they use receivers: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/v2.4

Answer (score 1):

Best answer I found on [Listen for Facebook logout with the LoginButton. (4.1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30039232/listen-for-facebook-logout-with-the-loginbutton-4-1?answertab=votes#tab-top)

```
private AccessTokenTracker fbTracker;
...
fbTracker = new AccessTokenTracker() {
            @Override
            protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(AccessToken accessToken, AccessToken accessToken2) {
                if (accessToken2 == null) {
                    Log.d("FB", "User Logged Out.");
                }
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also try using :

```
LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
```

So you could open your app then close it, then open it again and see if it's logged out:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
}
```