# Listen for Facebook logout with the LoginButton. (4.1)

Tags: java, android, facebook

I've been reading and haven't found a solution yet. So here goes.

I'm trying to upgrade to Facebook's new SDK 4.1 Android SDK.  I can successfully log in a user using the Facebook's LoginButton using this code: `facebookLogin.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>()....`

Once a user is logged in, I want to know when a user logs using the same button.  The login button changes to say "Log out" when a user is logged in.  What I want to know, is how can I listen for a successful log out from the LoginButton?  ( I know that`LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();` can log a user out.  But what I'm looking for is some sort of callBack which I can handle accordingly.)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Quoting the Facebook SDK [Upgrading the Android SDK from 4.0.1 to 4.1.0](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/change-log-4.x) docs: "Replacement Classes - Session and UserSettingsFragment have been removed and replaced by the LoginManager and AccessToken classes. LoginActivity is replaced by FacebookActivity."

Because I wanted to mimic the old Sessions changed listener logic, I looked further into the AccessTokenTracker.  Here's how I solved my problem.  I still use Facebook's LoginButton to Log out the user, but I also include this to listen for a change to a null token. Meaning the user logged out.

```
private AccessTokenTracker fbTracker;
    ...
    fbTracker = new AccessTokenTracker() {
                @Override
                protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(AccessToken accessToken, AccessToken accessToken2) {
                    if (accessToken2 == null) {
                        Log.d("FB", "User Logged Out.");
                    }
                }
            };
```

Hope this helps others in the future.

Comment: Excellent, this works. I would advise extending the `Application` class so a change in the `accessToken` will cause a logout globally.

Comment: Thank you Sir. This really helps.