# How can i clear the Facebook fields(image, name, gender) after Logout in android

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0

I'm unable to clear the fields of Facebook. I showed Image, Name, Gender. I want to clear this three fields when I click on Facebooklogoutbutton. Can anyone help me on this??

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private LoginButton loginButton;
private CallbackManager callbackManager;
private ProfilePictureView profilePictureView;
private LinearLayout infoLayout;
private TextView email;
private TextView gender;
private TextView username;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

/*We have to initialize before using any methods with sdkIntialise()*/
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(MainActivity.this);

    loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    email = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.email);
    gender = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.gender);
    username = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.vname);

    infoLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_info);
    infoLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    profilePictureView = (ProfilePictureView) findViewById(R.id.vimage);
    loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile, email, user_birthday"));

    /*initialize an instance of CallbackManager*/
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            GraphRequest graphRequest = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                    setProfileView(object);
                }
            });

            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email,gender,birthday");
            graphRequest.setParameters(parameters);
            graphRequest.executeAsync();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error to Login Facebook", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

private void setProfileView(JSONObject object) {

    try {
        email.setText(object.getString("email"));
        gender.setText(object.getString("gender"));
        username.setText(object.getString("name"));

        profilePictureView.setPresetSize(ProfilePictureView.NORMAL);
        profilePictureView.setProfileId(object.getString("id"));
        infoLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Just check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30039232/listen-for-facebook-logout-with-the-loginbutton-4-1

Answer (score 1):

Hi to logout you can use following code: 
Get the current access token then call fb logout function.

```
> if (AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() != null) {
>       LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();  
> }
```

After logout you have to refresh the layout or start same activity you need following code:

```
    Intent openMainActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);openMainActivity.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(openMainActivity);
```

Hope it helps

Comment: But i want clear the fields on UI i'm showing facebook fields image, name, email, id. When i click on login it is showing all these fields. but when i logout that required information is still showing..How can i clear the fields?

Comment: Restart ur activity through intent with flag clear_task new_task